# I cannot install WordPress 3.5.1

Tags: windows, wordpress

I've downloaded and installed XAMPP 1.8.1 on Windows. XAMPP control panel is running, Apache started and MySQL started.

When I click install.php in wordpress\wp-admin folder the following error comes up:

```
Error: PHP is not running

WordPress requires that your web server is running PHP. Your server does not have PHP installed, or PHP is turned off.
>
get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$wpdb->users'") != null ); // Ensure that Blogs appear in search engines by default $blog_public = 1; if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) $blog_public = isset( $_POST['blog_public'] ); $weblog_title = isset( $_POST['weblog_title'] ) ? trim( stripslashes( $_POST['weblog_title'] ) ) : ''; $user_name = isset($_POST['user_name']) ? trim( stripslashes( $_POST['user_name'] ) ) : 'admin'; $admin_password = isset($_POST['admin_password']) ? trim( stripslashes( $_POST['admin_password'] ) ) : ''; $admin_email = isset( $_POST['admin_email'] ) ? trim( stripslashes( $_POST['admin_email'] ) ) : ''; if ( ! is_null( $error ) ) { ?>

ERROR: %s' ), $error ); ?>
```

I have never worked with this tool and never worked with MySQL (where is MySQL?). How can I make WordPress work?

Comment: As per the error PHP is not running. You might first want to take a look at why it isn't switched on.

Comment: You don't install WP by clicking `install.php`. Instead, visit your new WP installation in a browser, and it should detect that it is a new installation, and will redirect to `install.php` for you. But first, check that your PHP/Apache installation is working correctly - try running `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in a php file in your browser.

Comment: "visit your new WP installation in a browser, and it should detect that it is a new installation, and will redirect to install.php for you". How should I do that? I've unpacked WordPress on my hard drive and there are some files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you accessing the file with a http request? (e.g. *http://localhost/mysite*). It could be a case of resetting the services (Apache and MySQL) or doing a clean install, but more information is required to assist.

A quick Google gives a number of solutions for this problem, see
[PHP not working in XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406433/php-not-working-in-xampp) or http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-xampp-and-virtual-hosts-please-help. Indeeed you could even try the [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) site, or just try Googling the error message.

There are a number of root causes and this problem can only have speculated answers unless you provide more detail on [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: I've reinstalled XAMPP and all is the same, which means PHP is not running.

Comment: I have never worked with this tools before. I'm .NET developer. First of all I don't know what to do after I installed XAMPP and downloaded WordPress. XAMPP is installed in C:\xampp. I've extracted WordPress files on different place. Is it ok?

Comment: Should I do something manually with MySQL database and if so what?

Comment: Also I don't know how WordPress works. Should I develop web site on my computer and upload it to some public host after that?

Comment: I really appreciate if somebody can help. Thanks.

Comment: Try this [step by step guide](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/installing-wordpress-on-local-windows-using-xampp/).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try. But, this is really bad that you can't set up all these things easily.

Comment: Where WordPress files should be? Should they be in some XAMPP folder or in any place on hard drive?

Comment: If you can't be bothered to read the answers provided you will find that "you can't set up all these things easily". Read the link, it tells you.

Comment: Your last link helped. I've set it up all. Thank you very much.

Comment: And one more thing. I've read I could create not only blogs with WordPress, but web sites as well. There's nothing about web sites. I can't see templates or something like that.

Comment: That's a bit beyond the scope of this question, remember Google is your friend. Try using the default theme and adding 'pages' rather than 'posts' to get started.