# localhost in XAMPP is displaying blank page without any error in MAC

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on my MAC OS X Sierra and when i am typing the localhost the welcome page of XAMPP is displaying but when i trying to open my any project  which was developed on my Windows XAMPP its displaying the white screen(A blank Page).

Though phpmyadmin is working fine. but i am not able to view my any of  project's. Help me out please! Can you help me out where i went wrong because apachewebserver and mysql Database is running in manager-osx

Comment: Checked the error logs ? Any error or code to provide ?

Comment: No there is no errors in file

Comment: because its opening in windows XAMPP!!!

Comment: Ok, I read about that. But if on the Mac Xampp, if you got a white screen, it means there's at least one error. Try to set the display error on for your project or look into the Apache error log file.

Comment: After trying a lot. I found that .html file is working but .php file is not working. Still @JazZ

Comment: There are lots of question relative to this on SO. See this one for example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406433/php-not-working-in-xampp. Good luck. ; )