# php isn't processed correctly

Tags: php, html, xampp

Thanks in advance for your help, I am pretty sure you can solve my problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      echo '<p>hello world</p>';
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Previous Code example does display

```
hello world
'; ?>
```

instead of the expected

```
hello world
```

This was run local with xampp V3.2.2 on a win10 OS and Chrome browser.
I hope I'm not the fiftieth person to ask this just because I couldn't google it correctly.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `echo 2+3;` what is the output ?

Comment: output is nothing. With:
    `echo "<p>".2+3."</p>";`
it's:
    `".2+3."`
    `"; ?>`

Comment: it seems php doen't work at all.try reinstalling xampp.and are you sure that you are running php correctly ?

Comment: I am sort of sure that it's running correctly. I just installed xampp and relied on it running correct.
I'll reinstall it and try to find the correct settings. So far you've helped me a lot. Didn't know xampp could be the problem.

Comment: Alright, I managed to get it working now thanks to you mentioning it must be xampp.
The problem was that I started the it with a `file://` url instead of `//localhost`.
Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406433/php-not-working-in-xampp
Thank you very much.