# PHP not executing with XAMPP (Windows)

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, xampp

(Edited for clarification) I am trying to execute some PHP code in a file called "index.php" using the Apache web server in XAMPP. The file is located at C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php.txt (not sure how to get rid of the .txt suffix). I am accessing the file by typing "http://localhost/index.php.txt" into my browser. The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
      <?php echo "It works!"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I select the file in the Apache server only the code itself shows up. I've been searching around for a while and I can't seem to find the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your log files

Comment: where this file is located and how you are accessing it?

Comment: This simply means that PHP isn't processing your file. Share your config file: httpd.conf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP not working in XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406433/php-not-working-in-xampp)

Comment: I looked around a bit. Got a "system cannot find path specified" error for the PHP error log. Can't find any PHP logs anywhere. The Apache error and access logs look fine.

Comment: Just rename the file `index.php.txt` to `index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code are not executing because the server interpret the file as text file, hence why the codes are not executing. This is due to your file name, which have .txt extension.

```
not sure how to get rid of the .txt suffix
```

Use any code editor like Notepad++ to save the file as PHP file, hence getting rid of the .txt extension.

Or for normal Windows Notepad, just select save as "all file", and the file name make sure only "index.php".